# Scala getting the adjacency list of each vertex from a list of source node and destination node

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm fairly new to Scala and GraphX, so this might be a trivial question. I'm trying to reverse the direction of each edge of a graph and then get the adjacency list of each vertex of the new reversed graph.
The input is in the form "FromNodeId \t ToNodeId"

```
0 1
0 2
1 2
1 3
```

I managed to reverse the directions of edges with the following code:

```
object Problem2{
    def main(args: Array[String]){
    val inputFile:String = args(0)
    val outputFolder = args(1)
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Problem2").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val input = sc.textFile(inputFile)
    val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc,inputFile)
    val newGraph = graph.reverse.edges
}
}
```

The output is of the form

```
Edge(1,0,1)
Edge(3,1,1)
Edge(2,1,1)
Edge(2,0,1)
```

My questions are, 
1. Is there a more efficient approach for the problem
2. how can I proceed to build the adjacency list for each vertex from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both questions is the [collectNeighbors and collectNeighborIds](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphOps).

For each vertex it computes the list of the neighbors. Notice the EdgeDirection parameter.

```
val vertices: RDD[(VertexId, String)] =  
    sc.parallelize(Array((1L,""), (2L,""), (4L,""), (6L,"")))


val edges: RDD[Edge[String]] = 
    sc.parallelize(Array(
        Edge(1L, 2L, ""),
        Edge(1L, 4L, ""),
        Edge(1L, 6L, "")))
val inputGraph = Graph(vertices, edges)

val verticesWithSuccessors: VertexRDD[Array[VertexId]] = 
    inputGraph.ops.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Out)
```

So as a graph is inmutable, you have to build a new one. Same edges, new vertices

```
val successorGraph = Graph(verticesWithSuccessors, edges)
```

And here a partial result:

```
val res = successorGraph.vertices.collect()
res: Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId,
         Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId])] = 
  Array((4,Array()), (1,Array(2, 4, 6)), (6,Array()), (2,Array()))
```